# script not working for included html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am following this http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp
to include html

So there is a html file i.e sidebar.html  which is included in various html files.

I want to keep a following sharing code like this in sidebar.html

```
<a id="fbshare" href="" target="_blank">  
    <img src="https://example1.com/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" />
</a>
```

But since there are more than 200 pages so I want to put the href according to the url of that html page.

So I am using this script in my main.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var share_url = document.URL;       

document.getElementById( "fbshare" ).href = 'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=' + share_url;
});
```

and this is the code for one of my html pages

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <header w3-include-html="header.html"></header>

    <main>

        <div id="main-slider" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="container">                 
                    <aside class="col-md-3 col-sm-4" w3-include-html="sidebar.html"></aside>

                </div>
            </div>

    </main>
    <footer w3-include-html="footer.html"></footer>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/owl.carousel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/w3data.js"></script>



     <script>
        w3IncludeHTML();
    </script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

But the script for writing href is not working..

I am stuck on this .Please help

Comment: You can easily do the includes with jQuery by using the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function. No need to include any of the `w3data.js` file.

Comment: Ya that will be the best option..  But is it not going to work if I do it via w3data.js

Comment: @user7459842 friendly advice, forget about w3data.js...

Comment: okay.. got it..

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.location.href` to get url of current page are you at. Then you can set href attribute to your element.

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var share_url = window.location.href;       

document.getElementById( "fbshare" ).setAttribute('href','http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=' + share_url);
});
```

EDIT:

After checking out w3 library that you're using, it seems that it is very limited and you should consider not using it. It does not provide any ability to run a callback when a content is loaded. Therefore, at time when your main.js is processed the element may `a` not be loaded yet. But, since you're using jQuery, you can use `.load` function. As such:

```
$( "header" ).load( "header.html", function() {
  $(this).find('a').attr('href', 'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+window.location.href);
});
```

And of course, remove the include directive from `header` (and from the others as well, and use load function to load them all as needed)

Comment: If you're only using `share_url` in one place, get rid of the variable and inline `window.location.href`...

Comment: @Adam Wolski thanks for the speedy reply..  I tried it but I am getting this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null

Comment: It seems that the header is not loaded yet in the DOM.

Comment: Oh..okay..  That was the reason that even google custom search form was not working.. I will read how to use the load function , implement it and get back to you ..But thanks a lot